# Can JavaScript run code sent to it from a server?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a `setInteral` pulling JSON from my server. Could I create a function in JavaScript that fetches the JSON from the server and executes it? For example,

```
{
  "command" : "alert('hello stack overflow');"
}
```

as a proof-of-concept?

I'm not seeing many security implications here as client-side code is being fetched from a trusted provider - the API (our server in this case).

Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks @CRice, that seems like what I'm curious for.

Comment: Why not just load JavaScript directly instead of JSON?

Comment: Better solution is to have code that command name with properties and have code that runs on the client that executes those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called `eval`. Use it upon your own head; it's a notorious security risk. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask for clarification as a new user why my question has been voted down? I'm trying rather hard to build up to 15 points and feel this isn't a off-topic question, nor a repeat. Much appreciated.

Comment: It isn't any more of a security risk than any other script you'd execute.

Comment: @ABCTaylor Most likely because two people happened think it was a silly question. I'm not sure that what you want to do is really wise; as pointed out by epascarello in a comment, it would usually be more reasonable to have a list of functions in your main script files and then execute the appropriate one of them as requested by the server. On the other hand if this is just some temporary thing for testing security's not an issue. Personally I don't approve of voting down this sort of question; the whole point of StackOverflow is for people to ask these things.